# Confuse with String and instance of

Tags: java, scjp

I am confusing about instanceof. My understanding is instanceof is check for object type. String is object but in the following program it show do not match. Please explain me.

```
public class MyTest
{
    static String s;
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String str = null;

        if(s instanceof String)
        {
            System.out.println("I am true String");
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("I am false String");
        }
        if(str instanceof String)
        {
            System.out.println("I am true String");
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("I am false String");
        }
    }    
}


The output is 

I am false String
I am false String
```

Thank advance.

Comment: `s` and `str` are ***null***. They are instanceof ***nothing***.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `instanceof` operator does not test the declared type of a variable; it tests the class of the object (if any) that is referenced by the variable. However, both `s` and `str` are `null` in your code and `null` is never an instance of any class. If you set `s` and/or `str` to an actual string, then the output will change accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

[JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/examples/InstanceofDemo.java)

> The instanceof operator compares an object to a specified type. You can use it to test if an object is an instance of a class, an instance of a subclass, or an instance of a class that implements a particular interface.

Check with creating new instance of the class

```
 String str = new String();
```

Comment: Nambi Narayanan --> Thank you very much.I will be try like that.